# How to construct the flow in function using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a function like below.

```
    public static List xyz(Map<String, String> m) {
      if(functionWithSomeLogic(m)) {
        return ImmutableList.of("A", "B");
      }
      if(functionWithSomeOtherLogic(m)) {
        return ImmutableList.of("C", "D");
      }
      List<String> collect = m.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
      return collect;
    }
```

I want to learn how to convert this function to use streams and return different lists based on conditions.

I want to be able to write like

```
`Optional.of(m).map(m->{if (functionWithSomeLogic(m)) return ImmutableList.of("A", "B")}`
```

But I am not able to keep in a single level if branching to different returns happens.

Basically I want the pipe to keep on operating the original object, and return a different object based on given conditions. At the same time keeping the pipe at same level.

Comment: There is no need to use streams here. Stick with what you have. (But consider using `return new ArrayList<>(m.keySet());` on the last line).

Comment: I want to learn how to do them just as a puzzle. I wont be able to learn if I stick to writing what I already know. This might not be a good idea in this case. But I will get a new understanding on how to do things.

Comment: `return Optional.of(m)
                       .map(x -> {
                           if (functionWithSomeLogic(x)) {
                               return ImmutableList.of("A", "B");
                           }
                           if (functionWithSomeOtherLogic(x)) {
                               return ImmutableList.of("C", "D");
                           }
                           return null;
                       })
                       .orElse(ImmutableList.copyOf(m.keySet()));` may be? but I don't like it too much

Comment: Just `return functionWithSomeLogic(m)? ImmutableList.of("A", "B"): functionWithSomeOtherLogic(m)? ImmutableList.of("C", "D"): ImmutableList.copyOf(m.keySet());` That’s “how to do it”, whether as a puzzle or as production code. If you ask, how to get a nail into the wall using a screwdriver, you won’t get a different answer than “don’t”.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ stackoverflow would never change. The whole community is just vile.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a map with all possible predicates and their values:

```
public class Temp2 {

   static final Map<Predicate<Map<String, String>>, List<String>> mapper = 
    ImmutableMap.of(
      Temp2::functionWithSomeLogic, ImmutableList.of("A", "B"),
      Temp2::functionWithSomeOtherLogic, ImmutableList.of("C", "D")
    );

   public static List<String> zyx(Map<String, String> m) {
       return mapper.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().apply(m))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> new ArrayList<>(m.values()));
   }
   //functionWithSomeLogic && functionWithSomeOtherLogic below
}
```

and call it as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();
    //...
    List<String> list = xyz(someMap);
}
```

Comment: this is like killing a fly with a machine-gun

Comment: @Eugene, is this bad? I mean if you have a lot of predicates like `functionWithSomeLogic` then it's better than `if if if ....`

Comment: if you have a lot of predicates... which the OP does not. that comment by Holger is the way to go, seriously

Comment: What is it's a really big fly?

Comment: Thanks, It's kind of new way to do it.